# Can the Basel problem be solved by Leibniz today?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta

It is well known that Leibniz derived the series
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4}&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1},\tag{1}
\end{align}$$
but apparently he did not prove that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}{6}&=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}.\tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Euler did, in 1741 (unfortunately, after the demise of Leibniz). Note that this was also before the time of Fourier.

My question: do we now have the tools to prove (2) using *solely* (1) as the definition of $\pi$? Any positive/negative results would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**Clarification**: I am not looking for a full-fledged rigorous proof of (1)$\Rightarrow$(2). An estimate that (2) *should* hold, given (1), would qualify as an answer.

Comment: It would be quite surprising if you could prove, or even give a heuristic argument, for (1) => (2).  They are values of two different $L$-functions (namely $\zeta(s)$ and $L(s,\chi)$ for the nontrivial character modulo $4$) at two different values of $s$ ($s=1$ v. $s=2$.)

Comment: No, Leibniz is dead.

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2454168/proving-left1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-right2-frac38-left-frac112/3361814#3361814

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Note that proving $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}6 \,\,\,\,\,\, (\spadesuit)$$ is equivalent to proving $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(2k+1)^2} = \dfrac{\pi^2}{8} \,\,\,\,\,\, (\clubsuit)$$ The hope for proving $(\clubsuit)$ instead of $(\spadesuit)$ is that squaring $\dfrac{\pi}4$ gives $\dfrac{\pi^2}{16}$ and adding this twice gives us $\dfrac{\pi^2}8$. We will in fact prove that $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(2k+1)^2} = \left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \right)^2$$
Since we know $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} = \dfrac{\pi}4$$ and $$\sum_{k=0}^{N} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} = \sum_{k=-(N+1)}^{-1} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)},$$
we have that $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} = \dfrac{\pi}2$$
Square the above to get
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \right)^2 & = \left(\sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \right) \left( \sum_{j=-N-1}^{j=N} \dfrac{(-1)^j}{(2j+1)} \right)\\
& = \sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \sum_{j=-N-1}^{j=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{(2k+1)(2j+1)}\\
& = \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \left(\dfrac1{(2k+1)} - \dfrac1{(2j+1)} \right) + \sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{2k}}{(2k+1)(2k+1)}
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\left(\sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \right)^2 - \sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+1)} = \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \left(\dfrac1{(2k+1)} - \dfrac1{(2j+1)} \right)$$
Let us now show that
$$\overbrace{\sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \left(\dfrac1{(2k+1)} - \dfrac1{(2j+1)} \right)}^{(\heartsuit)} \to 0 \text{ as } N \to \infty$$
We have
\begin{align}
(\heartsuit) & = \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \dfrac1{(2k+1)} - \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \dfrac1{(2j+1)}\\
& = \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \dfrac1{(2k+1)} + \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(k-j)} \dfrac1{(2j+1)}\\
& = 2 \times \left(\sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{2(j-k)} \dfrac1{(2k+1)} \right)\\
& = \sum_{\overset{j,k=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^{j+k}}{(j-k)} \dfrac1{(2k+1)} = \sum_{k=-N-1}^N \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \underbrace{\left(\sum_{\overset{j=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^N \dfrac{(-1)^{j}}{(j-k)}\right)}_{(\diamondsuit_{k})}
\end{align}
Let us simplify $(\diamondsuit_{k})$ a bit. Assuming $k \neq -N-1$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{\overset{j=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^N \dfrac{(-1)^{j}}{(j-k)} & = \sum_{j=k+1}^N \dfrac{(-1)^{j}}{(j-k)} + \sum_{j=-N-1}^{k-1} \dfrac{(-1)^{j}}{(j-k)}\\
& = \left(\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{1} + \dfrac{(-1)^{k+2}}{2} + \cdots + \dfrac{(-1)^{N}}{N-k}\right)\\
& + \left(\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(-1)} + \dfrac{(-1)^{k-2}}{(-2)} + \cdots + \dfrac{(-1)^{-N-1}}{-N-1-k}\right)\\
& = (-1)^{k+1} \sum_{j=N-\vert k \vert +1}^{N+\vert k \vert +1} \dfrac{(-1)^j}{j}
\end{align}
If $k = -N-1$, we have
$$\sum_{\overset{j=-N-1}{j \neq k}}^N \dfrac{(-1)^{j}}{(j-k)} = \sum_{j=-N}^N \dfrac{(-1)^{j}}{(j+N+1)} = (-1)^{N-1} \sum_{j=1}^{2N+1} \dfrac{(-1)^j}{j}$$
We now have
$$(\heartsuit) = \sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{(-1)^k \diamondsuit_k + (-1)^{-k-1} \diamondsuit_{-k-1}}{2k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac{(-1)^k \left(\diamondsuit_k - \diamondsuit_{-k-1} \right)}{2k+1}$$
Now for $k \geq 0$
\begin{align}
\left(\diamondsuit_k - \diamondsuit_{-k-1} \right) & = (-1)^{k+1} \sum_{j=N-k +1}^{N+k +1} \dfrac{(-1)^j}{j} - (-1)^{-k} \sum_{j=N-(k+1) +1}^{N+(k+1) +1} \dfrac{(-1)^j}{j}\\
& = 2 \cdot (-1)^{k+1} \cdot \sum_{j=N-k+1}^{N+ k +1} \dfrac{(-1)^j}{j} + (-1)^{N+1} \left( \dfrac1{N+k+2} + \dfrac1{N-k}\right)
\end{align}
Hence,
$$\left \vert \diamondsuit_k - \diamondsuit_{-k-1} \right \vert = \mathcal{O} \left( \dfrac1N\right)$$
$$\left \vert (\heartsuit) \right \vert \leq \sum_{k=0}^N \dfrac1{2k+1} \mathcal{O}(1/N) = \mathcal{O}(\log(2N+1)/N) \to 0$$
Hence,
$$\left(\sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \right)^2 - \sum_{k=-N-1}^{k=N} \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+1)} \to 0$$
Hence,
$$\left(\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)} \right)^2 = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)(2k+1)} = 2 \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(2k+1)^2} = 2 \cdot \dfrac34 \cdot \zeta(2)$$
Hence,$$\boxed{\zeta(2) = \dfrac23 \cdot \dfrac{\pi^2}4 = \dfrac{\pi^2}6}$$

Comment: This is a great answer! Quite $(\heartsuit)$ly.

Answer (score 4):

The idea that Leibniz's series 
$$\frac \pi 4 = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^i}{2i + 1} \tag{1}$$
could be used to prove Euler's
$$\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6} = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2} \tag{2}$$
seems even more tantalizing when you consider that $(2)$ is equivalent to
$$\frac{\pi^2}{8} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i+1)^2} \tag{3}.$$
The equivalence between $(2)$ and $(3)$ is clear from
$$\frac{3}{4}\zeta(2) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}- \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i)^2}= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2i+1)^2}.$$
Compare $(1)$ and $(3)$! My goodness.

Have you already looked at
[Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1n2) and http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf ?

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of the above relations. I found a reference that establishes that given one more ingredient, (1) is sufficient to infer (2) - as far as heuristic arguments go (see [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath477.htm)). Also, this [talk](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~vsv/oxfordtalktr.pdf) seems to indicate that Newton's theorem (which must have existed pre-Leibniz?) is sufficient to infer (2), again the rigor is forsaken.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best way without leibnizSince $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{4}$, we have

$$\frac{\pi^2}{16}=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{dydx}{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)}\overset{t=xy}{=}\int_0^1\int_0^x\frac{dtdx}{x(1+x^2)(1+t^2/x^2)}$$

$$=\frac12\int_0^1\int_t^1\frac{dxdt}{x(1+x^2)(1+t^2/x^2)}\overset{x^2\to x}{=}\frac12\int_0^1\left(\int_{t^2}^1\frac{dx}{(1+x)(x+t^2)}\right)dt$$

$$=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{4t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}\right)}{1-t^2}dt\overset{t=\frac{1-x}{1+x}}{=}-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}\right)}{x}dx$$

$$\overset{x^2\to x}{=}-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{x}dx=-\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{(1-x)^2}{1-x^2}\right)}{x}dx$$

$$=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx+\frac14\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx}_{x^2\to x}$$

$$=-\frac38\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\Longrightarrow \int_0^1\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

---

*Remark*:

This solution can be considered a proof that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ as we have $\int_0^1\frac{-\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=\text{Li}_2(x)|_0^1=\text{Li}_2(1)=\zeta(2)$

Comment: I upvoted for this question

Comment: In fact, this method of proof for $\zeta(2)=\pi^2/6$ generalizes nicely. Daniele Ritelli and myself published an AMS article to obtain values of other series by means of multiple integration. See here: https://www.ams.org/journals/qam/2018-76-03/S0033-569X-2018-01499-3/