# Calculate the sum of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n+12}{n^3+5n^2+6n}$

Tags: analysis

They tell me to find the sum of the series
$$\sum a_n :=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n+12}{n^3+5n^2+6n}$$
Since $\sum a_n$ is absolutely convergent, hence we can manipulate it the same way we would do with finite sums. I've tried splitting the general term and I get
$$\frac{n+12}{n(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{A}{n}+\frac{B}{n+2}+\frac{C}{n+3}=\frac{2}{n}+\frac{-5}{n+2}+\frac{3}{n+3}$$
and so
$$\sum a_n =\sum \frac{2}{n}-\frac{5}{n+2}+\frac{3}{n+3}$$
Now, if I was to split the series in the sum of three different series I would get three different divergent series and so, obviously $\sum a_n$ wouldn't converge.
I also suspect about being a telescopic series althought the numerators of each fraction makes it difficult to find the cancellation terms. I also know that I can rearrange the terms in my series, althought I cannot see how would this solve the problem.

If anyone could give me a hint I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Compute them up to $p$ and not $\infty$, recombine and make $p\to \infty$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, for every $N \in \mathbb{N}^*$, one has
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n &=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{2}{n}-\frac{5}{n+2}+\frac{3}{n+3}\\
&=2 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} - 5 \sum_{n=3}^{N+2} \frac{1}{n} + 3 \sum_{n=4}^{N+3} \frac{1}{n}\\
&=2 \left(1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \sum_{n=4}^N \frac{1}{n} \right) - 5 \left( \frac{1}{3} + \sum_{n=4}^N \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{N+2} \right)\\
&\quad + 3 \left( \sum_{n=4}^N \frac{1}{n} +  \frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{N+2}   + \frac{1}{N+3} \right)\\
&= 2 - 5 \left( \frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{N+2} \right) + 3 \left( \frac{1}{N+1} + \frac{1}{N+2}   + \frac{1}{N+3}  \right)
\end{align*}

Now just let $N$ tend to $+\infty$ to see that $$\boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n = 2}$$

Comment: Nice(⇧+) Can you help solve [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4309373/trying-to-prove-left1-frac13-frac15-frac17-cdots-right2-frac38-left-f)

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to play with harmonic numbers, it is pretty simple

$$\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1 {n}=H_p$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1 {n+2}=H_{p+2}-\frac{3}{2}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p \frac 1 {n+3}=H_{p+3}-\frac{11}{6}$$

Now, use three times the asymptotics
$$H_q=\log (q)+\gamma +\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12 q^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^4}\right)$$ and continue with Taylor or long division and you will have
$$\sum_{n=1}^{p}\frac{n+12}{n^3+5n^2+6n}=2-\frac{1}{p}-\frac{3}{p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Use it for $p=10$; the approximation gives exactly $1.87$ while the exact value is $\frac{1615}{858}=1.88228$ so a relative error of $0.65$%.

Comment: $\to 2 $ as $p \to \infty$ (⇧+) ✌️

Comment: @I_don't_know_maths_. Are you sure ? (just kidding). Cheers :-)

Comment: Haha! *Compute them up to p and not ∞, recombine and make  p→∞* You already said.
Just like Euler the great who knew $\frac1n$ diverges he then came up with the partial sum of harmonic numbers. 
*You have done somewhat same* say (p = 10 or 20)

Comment: @I_don't_know_maths_. I almost never "play" with $0$ or $\infty$